# Javascript if/else onclick help

Tags: javascript

I have a simple animation in CSS3 called `"tap"` and `"untap"`.

I call it in via `" className"`, and I'm trying to combine it so that `onclick` it does "tap" and `onmouseout` to "untap".

I have the click part working, but after the `else` statement it "doesn't work". What am I doing wrong?

---

```
<img src="picHere.gif" id="img7" onclick="if(this.className != 'tap') { this.className='tap'}  else {"onmouseout='this.className='untap'}; "/>
```

Comment: Can you improve on your question title? A list of technologies doesn't describe the problem, and "help" is completely redundant.

Comment: You would be better off using an event handler added with a DOM method like `document.getElementById('img7').onclick=function(){}`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this:

```
<img src="picHere.gif" id="img7" 
    onclick="if(this.getAttribute('class') !== 'tap') this.setAttribute('class','tap');" 
    onmouseout="if(this.getAttribute('class') === 'tap') this.setAttribute('class','untap');" />
```

You could actually keep `className`, if you wanted. But the important thing to note here is that the `onclick` and `onmouseout` events are seperate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interleave the event handlers like that. Try this:

```
<img src="picHere.gif" id="img7" onclick="this.className='tap';" onmouseout='this.className='untap';" />
```

If you're willing to use jQuery, you could do something like this, which is cleaner yet:

```
<img src="picHere.gif" id="img7" />

// in your JavaScript code
$('#img7').click(function() { $(this).addClass('tap'); })
          .mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass('tap'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just invalid markup. Change it to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onclickHandler(sender) {
        if (sender.className != 'tap') { 
            sender.className = 'tap';
        }
        return false;
    }
    function onmouseoutHandler(sender) {
        if (sender.className == 'tap') {
            sender.className = 'untap';
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<img src="picHere.gif" 
     id="img7" 
     onclick="return onclickHandler(this);" 
     onmouseout="return onmouseoutHandler(this);" />
```

Comment: You could also use `document.getElementById()` to attach the event handler.